# How can I track changes (User Activity) on an MS-SQL database hosted on Amazon RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a set of databases on an Amazon RDS Instance. The version is SQL Server 2008 R2 and as far as I understand I cannot simply set up an audit via Management Studio. I am considering creating a table which will be filled by  my ASP.Net application upon attempting a query, however this will not track a user that has made changes directly to my databases outside the application.

Does the Amazon console have anything to track database changes/user activity?

Thank you SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using audit triggers on the tables you wish to track.

This article 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/ 
describes how to implement a simple audit trigger.

Comment: This is a really good answer, I've tried it out and it does exactly what I want, I would give you another +1 for the tone of the linked article if I could.